# TinyXML2 cannot count number of tags

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file like the following:

```
<transaction>

<day>20</day>
<month>2</month>
<year>2014</year>

<product>
    <barcode>123456789012</barcode>
    <type>Food</type>
    <price>12</price>
    <currency>gbp</currency>
    <name>Oreo</name>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
</product>

<product>
    <barcode>123456789012</barcode>
    <type>Food</type>
    <price>12</price>
    <currency>gbp</currency>
    <name>Oreo</name>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
</product>
```

Now I want to parse it using TinyXML2 and have written the following code:

```
  int count = 0;
  int product_count = 0;
  std::string prod_id("product");
  //Get first node inside the root node then start iterations from there
  XMLNode* node = doc.FirstChild()->FirstChild();
  for(node; node; node=node->NextSibling()){
    std::cout << node->Value() << std::endl;
    count++;
    std::string tag( node->Value());
    if(tag.compare(prod_id)){
      std::cout << "Product found!" << std::endl;
      product_count++;
    }
  }



  std::cout << "There are " << count << " tags in total" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "There are " << product_count  << " products in total" << std::endl;
```

However the output that I am getting is the following:

```
day
Product found!
month
Product found!
year
Product found!
product
product
There are 5 tags in total
There are 3 products in total
```

In essence the code says that for some reason day == product. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the return value of [`compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)

Compare does not return a `bool`, it returns a number instead:

- negative if a < b
- zero if a == b
- positive if a > b

So in your case it returns `0` because the two strings are equal, therefore your if is executed on non-equal strings. Use

```
if (tag.compare(prod_id) == 0) {
```

Comment: well just one word. #embarrassment